# How to override package functionality?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using a package [Laravel Addresses](https://packagist.org/packages/vendocrat/laravel-addresses). This package uses `city` as an attribute of the model Address. Whereas have a separate model of `City` and I want to create `hasOne` relationship of `Address` model with that of `City`.

How can I override this outside of the vendors folder?

Answer (score 0):

After running `php artisan vendor:publish`

Try editing the migration 'create addresses table' and change

`$table->string('city',60);`

to

```
$table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
```

Then go on to create the relationship in the models i.e

In the City Model

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

And create a new Address Model with `php artisan make:model Address` and add the following:

```
protected $table = "addresses";
public function city()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\City');
}
```

You can then copy the other methods if you'll need them